# Enable and disable button with ajax content response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot get why its not working with me. I know to enable and disable button using `attr` and `prop`.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btn", function(){
      $(this).html("Sending...");
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
      // I have ajax content here. and in success of ajax. run
      $(this).prop("disabled",false);
```

The button disable is not enabled in ajax success. Do my code has any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside ajax do not use `$(this)`, instead you can do this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(){
     var button = $(this);
```

Inside ajax, then you can use this:

```
button.prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: oh what a silly mistake. I knew it but then also mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: so i think that the problem in referencing using "this" try using the element id

Answer (score 0):

You need to save a reference to `this` if you wish to refer to it in another function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(){
    var button = $(this);
    button.html("Sending...");
    button.prop("disabled",true);
    // I have ajax content here. and in success of ajax. run
    button.prop("disabled",false);
```

See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` in AJAX does not refer to the button, instead use:

```
$('#btn').prop("disabled",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use async : true as below :)

```
$('#button').attr("disabled", true);
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            complete: function(response){
                $('#button').attr("disabled", false);
            },
        });
```